# Spring RestTemplate handle custom status code

Tags: java, spring, http-headers, resttemplate

I should call some service from my application that can return unusual http status codes, such as 230, 240 etc. By default error handler I'm getting:

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.UnknownHttpStatusCodeException: Unknown status code [230] null] with root cause...
```

When I use my custom error handler I can avoid this:

```
@Override
    public boolean hasError(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException {

        int status = response.getRawStatusCode();
        if (status >= 200 && status <= 299)
            return false;

        HttpStatus statusCode = response.getStatusCode();
        if (statusCode.is2xxSuccessful())
            return false;
        HttpStatus.Series series = statusCode.series();
        return (HttpStatus.Series.CLIENT_ERROR.equals(series)
                || HttpStatus.Series.SERVER_ERROR.equals(series));
    }
```

But when RestTmplate tries to retrieve it falls into the same exception in `MessageBodyClientHttpResponseWrapper`:

```
public boolean hasMessageBody() throws IOException {
        HttpStatus responseStatus = this.getStatusCode();
        if (responseStatus.is1xxInformational() || responseStatus == HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT ||
                responseStatus == HttpStatus.NOT_MODIFIED) {
            return false;
        }
        else if (this.getHeaders().getContentLength() == 0) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

How can I get response body correctly?

Comment: Spring's `HttpStatus` is an enumeration, and there is no support for unassigned HTML codes. You have two options, basically: 1. overwrite all offending code (use your own implementations that don't call to that enumeration, only using raw status code) on the path of processing those responses; 2. request enhancement from Spring team (there might [already be one](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-14205)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, issue solved in `Spring 5`, [tested it](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-15978).